# How to paste data to specific cell range?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba and need a little help. I have a sheet named "Archive" which will have 12 sets of data displayed/structured in somewhat of a table format. My goal is to pull data from other sheets within the same workbook and paste it in a specific range that corresponds to the appropriate "table" for that data. Here is my code for data that is being pulled from a sheet named "Daily DB" and is being pasted to the "Archive" sheet.

```
Sub GetDailyDataByWeek()

Dim cw As Integer    ' current week
Dim lr As Long    'last row of data
Dim i As Long    ' row counter

'Clear exsisting contents
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A5:E11").ClearContents

'Get week number and year of current date
cw = Format(Date, "ww")

With Worksheets("Daily DB")

    ' Find last row of data
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    For i = 2 To lr
        If Format(.Cells(i, 1).Value, "ww") = cw Then
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5)).Copy
            Worksheets("Archive").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,    0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This code does what I want it to do. The line that I need help in fixing is:

```
 Worksheets("Archive").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,    0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
```

As this line looks for the last row of data, which in my case would be the header row of the 12th table. However, I'd like this particular data to go into the first table which after the header row starts at "A5", but I'm not sure how to go about that. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If each paste needs to go in sequential row, starting from A5, then A6, then A7, etc., Try: `Worksheets("Archive").Range("a5").Offset(i - 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats`.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion but it didn't work properly, I believe due to the fact the "i" is referring to another sheet "Daily DB" and not to "Archive" which is where the data is being paste to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the data from another cell or range into the same workbook I would use the "Value" method of the Range object, like this:

```
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets("XXX").Range("Z" & j).Value
```

By doing it like this you would avoid doing all the copy and paste operations.

If you dont want to specify a Range for each value, you could activate the firs cell of the first row and then "offset" your way through, like this:

```
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & i).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = blah blah blah
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 'If you want to move to the next row (same column)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate 'If you want to move to the next column (Same row)
```